# Alert Dialog Box Theme Issue

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting an error when trying to set theme for alertDialogbox. I am betting white box behind the alertdialogbox. Any idea how i can get rid of it? Here is my code for styles.xml.
[image]

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnchanged|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/alertTheme</item>
</style>

   <style name="alertTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    </style>
```

Comment: It isn't an answer but maybe help you. Use `AlertDialog` from support library and stylize it. Just I too try to stylize `AlertDialog` and have a lot of problem with old Android versions.

Comment: Have you tried setting the parent of your `alertTheme` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert`?

Comment: Yes i did but it changes the appearance of the button on the dialog which i do not want.

Comment: U can create your custom dialog theme but this is not a bug. Same dialog box shows by theme `Theme_Holo_Dialog` but with dark color. Take look at this link: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44224/displayalert-alertdialog-styling-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In your `values` res folder**, your `alertDialogTheme` should have the following property:

`<!-- In API <21, this gives a funky background. Set to translucent -->
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/translucent</item>`

where @color/translucent is defined in colors.xml as `#00000000`, which gives opacity of 0.

**In your `values-v21` res folder**, your `alertDialogTheme` should have the following property:

`<!-- In API 21+, this is the dialog background color -->
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/someColor</item>`

This does nothing to alertDialogs in any API as far as I can tell:

`<!--<item name="android:colorBackground">...</item>-->`

I've only tested this on the Light AppCompat theme.

Answer (score 1):

You do not provide any code, but in any way you should use **AppCompat**.

Your dialog style should inherit from `AppCompat.Dialog`

```
<style name="AlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"/>
```

and you should *only* use the AppCompat `AlertDialog`. Additionally you then pass in *your* style to the constructor.

```
new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.AlertDialog).show();
```

### Without AppCompat

If you chose to try without AppCompat, be sure to test on multiple devices. You will need to provide different themes for phones before and after API 21 and handling the `android:windowBackground` yourself by either setting or hiding it.

Comment: didnt work. It changes the look of the button. I want the button to look same as in the picture

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your alertTheme

```
<item name="android:background">@null</item>
```

Comment: This might lead to a bug where the background is not visible at all on other devices

Comment: This comment is solely based on my experience. I had this issue multiple times and it all depends on appcompat or not, which theme your parent is, and the device api

Comment: I've gotten stuck styling an `AlertDialog` before and I ended up using `HierarchyViewer` to analyze its structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes a little bit improved answer of samGbos:

**values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/SplashScreenDialog</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/SplashScreenDialog</item>
</style>
...
<style name="SplashScreenDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**values-v21/styles.xml**

```
...
<style name="SplashScreenDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
</style>
```